# Difference between "deliver" and "send"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

In the (7) blank the answer is " Deliver " but can we use " Send " instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, **send** won’t fit this context because the speech is being delivered (is being read by the queen on TV and heard by people)

Let’s assume you use **send** instead. How is that going to change the meaning?

- if you say send the speech, i will understand that the queen, while on TV, is sending physical/digital copy of speech to every single citizen in the UK. In this case, Send makes zero sense.

For example,

- Trump delivers speech to people on a weekly basis.

The other thing is that you need to know the words that come together and they are referred to in English as **collocations**. You can search them up on google to determine which verbs are possible to use before a specific word.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Deliver" and "send" have **partially** overlapping fields of meaning. But in the most frequent usage, they have completely different meanings.

When you put a piece of mail into a letter box or when you tell your email software to get your email to a particular email address, you are sending something. "Sending" starts the process of getting something from A to B. When the mail service puts that letter into the mailbox of the addressee or when the addressee's email software beeps "You've got mail," that is delivering something."Delivery" ends the process of getting something from A to B. When a woman gives birth, she "delivers her baby."

Unfortunately, that clear distinction between beginning and end does not apply in all cases. With speeches, the very act of speaking ensures that the listeners receive the message almost instantaneously. Although the physicists can show there is a very brief interval between when the sound is uttered and when it is heard, they are considered for purposes of English usage to be actually instantaneous. Thus, giving a speech is said to be delivering a speech.

Answer (score -2):

deliver means *to make things under being seized go out*

For instance, the doctor delivered twins to her.

Deliver us from evil.

Since she was grabbing the message, then deliver is suitable.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Virtually all of this answer is not idiomatic.